# Project Naming Convention

Tags: visual-studio, naming-conventions, projects-and-solutions

I am in a debate about what a best practice would be for naming projects within a .sln on our team. We are working in Visual Studio and debating about what the project naming and placement of classes should be. Here are the two arguments:

1. There should be a "Common" project which will contain two folders: "Contracts" and "Model". Within "Contracts" folder will be the interfaces and of course within "Model" folder will be the data model. The advantage to this is that there will only be one .dll published which will have both the model and contracts within it.
2. There should be a "Model" project and a "Contracts" project. "Model" project should contain the data model and the "Contracts" project will contain the interfaces. The advantage here is in the naming, you know what will be in each .dll.

So simplified the question really is, is it better to have two separate projects or one project for the interfaces and model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd separate them into separate projects. Your solution will likely include more DLLs, and you'll want to be able to access the interfaces from any of them. If you dump them into the same DLL with your Models, you run a higher risk of a circular dependency down the road.

Comment: The other issue is that if your Model ends up including references to persistence concerns, you don't have to pull those into other parts of your application, you can just reference the Contracts dll.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, I would keep projects on RE USABILITY basis. Means each project specific to content oriented.

Also note even after keeping separate you can [merge](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx) them in single dll. So you objective of naming will also be achieved.